# table layout adjustment for accordian

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to display accordian in table layout. But, after expanding their formation is getting disturbed.

Here I am trying to check the table layout for accordion [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krthk2005/dypLh32p/7/).

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime" />Open only one at a time</label>
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group  heading="Static Header">This content is straight in the template.</accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">{{group.content}}</accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
        <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
        <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

While clicking on first accordion it expands but it also disturbs the bottom one.
The mockup given to me is:

[image: here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accordion is from the [angular-ui-botstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) so **bootstrap style** should be included (and already included), so 
your solution is to use the [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)  (using row class and col class)

For this example,I use **col-xs-4** only to force to display all 3 columns in fiddle.

```
   <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
       <div class="row">

         <div class="col-xs-4">
            <accordion-group heading="Static Header">This content is straight in the template.</accordion-group>
            <accordion-group heading="Static Header">This content is straight in the template.</accordion-group>
            <accordion-group heading="Static Header">This content is straight in the template.</accordion-group>
         </div>  

         <div class="col-xs-4">
            <accordion-group heading="Static Header">This content is straight in the template.</accordion-group>
            <accordion-group  heading="Static Header">This content is straight in the template.</accordion-group>
            <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">{{group.content}}</accordion-group>
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-4">
              <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
                <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
                <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
                <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
              </accordion-group>
              <accordion-group  heading="Static Header">This content is straight in the template.</accordion-group>
              <accordion-group  heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">{{group.content}}</accordion-group>
        </div>

    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y03r5as2/1/

And remove the css style, you dont need that.

NB: you can follow the [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) documentation to adjust it for your need by adding **col-sm-**  & **col-md-** and **col-lg-** too, to have different look for every screen large. Or only col-xs-, if you want to force 3 columns for all scren...

---

### **UPDATE: build the accordion from dynamic data**

From a dynamic data, which is an array like: `[item1, item2, ...]`,the best approach is to transform this data in the controller.
You just divise this array to 3 new array inside array like:
 `[[item1,item2,...], [item6,...], [item9, ...]]`

Here's a simple function which divise your data :

```
   function separateArray(arr, size) {
      var newArr = [];
      var colsLength = Math.ceil(arr.length/size);
      for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=colsLength) {
        newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+colsLength));
      }
      return newArr;
    }
```

and use it like:

```
$scope.transformedGroups = separateArray($scope.groups, 3);
```

it separate your data to 3 arrays: `[[item1,item2,...], [item6,...], [item9, ...]]`

And now you can have 3 cols easily with:

```
<div class="row">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
         <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="rows in transformedGroups">
           <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}"  ng-repeat="group in rows">{{group.content}}</accordion-group>
         </div>
   </accordion>
</div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrev7gL7/1/

Comment: I think that this would be the correct way to go. Tables can be difficult to read for people that are visually impaired (using a screen reader).

Comment: If you decide to use bootstrap, be sure to add additional column classes. Having 3 columns on an extra small screen size is probably not the best solution, you'll want the data to stack at col-xs. What you're looking for is: <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> See my answer & fiddle below if you need your data to stack in a specific order

Comment: He already use bootstrap. The accordion is from uib-bootstrap. The reason why I put xs is to show in jsfiddle since he want 3 cols

Comment: I guess I meant to say "If you decide to use bootstrap formatting for this particular situation..."

Comment: @ciammarino xs here is just an example to show how to achieve 3 cols. If you open the fiddle without col-xs-4 it wont show us the 3 columns and user may think it doesnt work.

Comment: Hi @FetraR. Data will be coming from server. So I am unable to keep 3 divs in static way. I updated my fiddle and also you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krthk2005/dypLh32p/7/)

Comment: @Kartheeks I updated my answer, best approach is to transform data in controller.

Comment: @FetraR.Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Using bootstrap for this particular layout can be a good solution for you. Giving you a table layout without table markup and allowing your data to stack on smaller screen sizes cutting out the possibility of the dreaded horizontal scroll.

As I said in my comment above, you'll definitely want to be sure your data stacks at the xs screen size (<=767px):

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs">
```

However, if you need the data to stack by column rather than row, then you'll need to wrap the data into a single row and nest individual rows within the columns. [See my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ciammarino/s96m8ae0/4/).

**UPDATE-9/20/17:10:30EST**

I am a goof!  I cannot believe I didn't recommend this to begin with! I believe a [flex-container and flex-items](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the best solution to achieve your specs. I've started a [NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ciammarino/00ewLmpL/) which should be a good start.

Comment: Using bootstrap grid is already the solution I provided in my answer. the xs is just an example to force display all 3 columns.

Comment: Hi @ciammarino. Data will be coming from server. I use ng-repeat and those divs create using ng-repeat. I updated my fiddle and also you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krthk2005/dypLh32p/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I found that you are used the css for panel like

```
.panel{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
}
```

Please try to change the css for panel like as follows

```
.panel{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}
```

I will work.

Comment: If you have any questions let me know I will give you clarification.

Comment: I need to show 3 panel columns per row. You can try in js fiddle

Comment: I have understood your problem.

Comment: Are you using any grid system like bootstrap css?